# ImportError: No module named 'kzyvad'

Tags: python

I want to start up a project, which imports a module named kzyvad. It occurs error `ImportError: No module named 'kzyvad'`. However, if I execute `pip install kzyvad`, it returns `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kzyvad`.

Did someone ever successfully install kzyvad?

Comment: Is there any module named `kzyvad`? There is even no search result in the `pypi` for this name.

Comment: @PerryLee How many python version is in your computer? it may mess things up when you have different python versions.

Comment: I don't think Python Versions does effect on module except module dependency but in @PerryLee case there is no any module available named 'kzyvad'

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you found your module but I looked for it and I could not find it, I think the guy who wrote 'kzyvad' did a mistake while writing, and if pip gives you this error, it means it doesn't exist.

Comment: I agree with @Sozy there's no any module named 'kzyvad' nor even a repository on #github

Comment: This page is the only result on SO and there aren't any real results anywhere else on the web

Answer (score 1):

If this `kzyvad.py` is written by you, then keep this file/module in a same folder and do this in `main.py` file:

```
from kzyvad import *
```

You can use it's functions and classes in your `main.py` file

Comment: yes this looks like a custom module. I'd recommend the poster also to look for it on the computer/ server or where he/she got the script from, maybe it is somewhere...